# How do I redirect specific URLs to specific pages using mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'd like to redirect localhost/website/setup to localhost/website/setup.php.

This is the mod_rewrite rule currently used:

```
RewriteRule ^setup/$ setup.php [L]
```

This works for redirecting localhost/website/setup/ to localhost/website/setup.php. However, as soon as the trailing slash is removed, it no longer works (it redirects me to localhost/setup/), even if I do not add the trailing slash in the rewrite rule. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part `^setup/$` is regular expressions so you can just do this

```
RewriteRule ^setup/*$ setup.php [L]
```

Comment: As far as I can see, that would only allow me to add more stuff after the trailing slash, but I want to be able to remove the trailing slash alltogether.

Comment: * "Matches the preceding item 0 or more times." So you could have many slashes in a row and it would still match but it should also allow you to have no slash at all. [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions)

If you want you could do something like `^setup(/|)$` and that would only have / or no slash at the end.

Comment: Hmm, apparently once it redirected setup/ to something wrong, whenever I updated my rewrite rule it failed - that was the reason I thought it did not work. When I use other aliases than setup it works, so thanks!